# Derivation of Quantifier Shift: $(\forall x)Lx \wedge (\forall y)My \vdash (\forall x)[Lx \wedge (\forall y)My]$

Tags: solution-verification, predicate-logic

I am working on proving a bunch of quantifier shift equivalencies and am currently stuck on how to derive: $(\forall x)Lx \wedge (\forall y)My \vdash (\forall x)[Lx \wedge (\forall y)My]$. I have the following attempt, but it seems too straightforward, so I think I am doing something wrong:

[image]

Please let me know if anyone has any advice or suggestions as to how I could go about this instead.

Comment: All good, there's nothing wrong with your solution -- not all proofs are difficult :) Here is a site to check your ND derivations: https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your assistance, I will check that out.